# Can't disable App Transport Security for http with iOS 11

Tags: ios

I've never had any problems disabling ATS in the past, but now I just can't connect to a http url at all (keep getting "ERROR: Cannot contact server with http scheme. Only https allowed"). I've tried a few things in the info.plist from reading past questions, but none of them solve the issue. Here's the current content of my info.plist

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <dict>
            <key>domainTheAppIsTryingToContact.com</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <true/>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
```

Why is the above not enabling me to connect over http?

If I just use NSAllowsArbitraryLoads on its own without NSExceptionDomains it doesn't work either (I'm just experimenting using NSExceptionDomains in an attempt to get things to work) - so why therefore does the documentation for ATS state this:

> If (NSAllowsArbitraryLoads) set to YES, disables all ATS restrictions
>   for all network connections

That's not a true statement, its obviously NOT disabling all ATS restrictions for all network connections if I'm getting "ERROR: Cannot contact server with http scheme. Only https allowed"

UPDATE: I ran /usr/bin/nscurl --ats-diagnostics for the url and everything failed.
However, that just brings me back to that Apple documentation statement again - if all nscurl combinations failed, then doesn't that just point to: " If (NSAllowsArbitraryLoads) set to YES, disables all ATS restrictions for all network connections" being a false statement once more.

Comment: @matt. I can connect to this url using a web brower, using curl, etc. oh and I can also connect using an Android equivalent version of the app. So if this is nothing to do with iOS then thats very curious that there is only a problem with iOS but not with a brower, not with curl, not with Android, not with anything else. Only iOS. So what could the issue be with the server then would result in exhibiting issues only when accessed from iOS  yet simultaneously not being anything to do with iOS?

Comment: It's your server which returns this error, this is not related to iOS. The server host has disabled connections with http. The statement from Apple documentation is still true however, as it disables Apple security for http, but it can't deal with server custom implementations…

Comment: @AnthoPak "The server host has disabled connections with http". I can enter the url into a web browser and its fine, so therefore how can a browser (and curl for that matter) have no problems if the server as disabled connections with http? Surely it cannot have otherwise the url would not be accessable via a browser.  (the url is prefixed wtih http://, not ftp, for example  just to be clear that the browser isn't using another protocol).

Comment: What is weird is that your error message really seems to be a custom one (as Google search doesn't return any result). So it may be a bad configuration on the server that returns this error… If you were able to give us the url it would be easier for us to investigate.

Comment: What is the error codes did you get with `nscurl`? And I agree with @anthopak that the url would be helpful.

Comment: Please update your question with what method is returning the error. It is not clear if this is an NSError returned by a URLSession method, an HTTP response body, etc

Comment: @quellish that error is shown in the log for the handset, its not returned by any API call.

Comment: @Gruntcakes Can you provide a trace of the network session using an HTTP debugging proxy, Wireshark, or similar?

Answer (score -2):

If you are still in prototyping/development mode, you should be able to change `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` to `NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent`, which allowed me to run the following and load the page:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
  webview.load(URLRequest.init(url:URL.init(string:"http://example.com")!))
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I previously tried that and it makes no difference (I'm not loading a web page however, I'm accessing a server).

Comment: Interesting - are you using a particular URL request framework (like Alamofire, etc.) or `URLSession`?  Also, from time to time I've had to clean the project to get `Info.plist` changes to stick.  Definitely post the answer if you find it; there are a lot of stackoverflow pages on ATS!

Comment: I'm using NSURLConnection (I know its deprecated, but that shouldn't matter for this). I've done a clean and rebuild and reinstallation.