# IOS cordova app always return 400 and bad request when fetch HTTP url

Tags: ios, cordova, sencha-touch

I have IOS app and android app built on top of cordova , i know both of the OS block http request, but in android I can configure it by adding some code in androidManifest.xml, in IOS everything i did none of them work, heres what i did

1. **added this to info.pslist**

> ```
>   <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
>           <dict>
>               <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
>               <true/>
>           </dict>
> ```

2. **added AllowCleartextTraffic** in config.xml

   `<preference name="AllowCleartextTraffic" value="true" />`

Im using **`XMLHttpRequest`** libs to fetch the url , thank you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51755041/cant-disable-app-transport-security-for-http-with-ios-11

Comment: that doesnt contain any answer @Eric